# Is it possible to export 3D model data from SimUrban?

Tags: convert, 3d, 3d-model

Today I came across a 3D modelling package I haven't seen before - [SimUrban](http://www.simmersionholdings.com/products/simurban.html).

[image]

The client wants to migrate their SimUrban project to a more modern system, and the provider who built it is no longer in business.

The person using SimUrban wasn't an expert, and we couldn't see any UI controls to export the data into another format.

I didn't get a chance to inspect the system in detail, but it appeared that there was a directory containing many *blah.model* files, which presumably comprised the 3D buildings shown in the system.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to export the building models from SimUrban into a commonly-used 3D modelling format such as VRML, DXF, DGB or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wrote to SimUrban and received this reply, which suggests that it is not possible to export the building models directly from SimUrban.

> Simurban is a closed system and most of the native files can’t be
> exported or migrated to another system.
>
> The terrain height data can be exported as points only in ASCII
> format.
>
> The base data sets are:
>
> - Terrain height - .dxf
> - Ortho Aerial Photography - .tiff with .tfw
> - 3D Models - .3ds (from 3ds Max) or .vrml (from Microstation)
> - 2D trees / billboards .bmp or .jpg